# EEGLAB: analysis of an specific section of an EDF file

Tags: matlab, seconds, eeglab, european-data-format

I need to analize just one minute of a EEG test which last around 50 minutes. The part to be analized is around the minute 10, but I can't access only to that part, because EEGLAB loads always from the begining of the test by default.

When loading the EDF file, EEGLAB has the option: Data range (in seconds) to read (default all [num num]).  I have tried here to insert only the time range needed, but I always get the begining of the test.

Comment: Have you followed [the steps in the manual](https://eeglab.org/tutorials/07_Extract_epochs/Extracting_Data_Epochs.html) to extract data epochs?

Comment: you can do this relatively easy in the GUI. If you plot the data there, you can manually select it and choose to delete it

Comment: Thanks @SaaruLindestøkke for your reply.  I previously followed the steps in the manual as you suggest

Comment: Thanks @Douwe  for your reply.  The solution proposed is actually useful.  Anyway, what I did is to select the menu Edit --> Select data, and then I could select only the range that I needed.

Comment: if you use ` EEG = pop_clean_rawdata(EEG, 'FlatlineCriterion',5,'ChannelCriterion',0.8,'LineNoiseCriterion',4,'Highpass','off','BurstCriterion','off','WindowCriterion','off','BurstRejection','on','Distance','Euclidian'); % deletes bad chns and bad periods` it auto deletes bad data for you. You might want to check what criterion work for you.